# Select Option, Value Result from database

Tags: php, laravel

I already get the data from the database

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
    <select multiple name="store_type[]" required="">
        <option selected="" disabled="">{{$value->store_type}}</option>
        <option value="Dine-in">Dine-in</option>
        <option value="Take-out">Take-out</option>
        <option value="Home Delivery">Home Delivery</option>
        <option value="Drive Thru">Drive Thru</option>
    </select>   
    <label>Store Type</label>
</div>
```

. I want the output selected those result individually.

**Example:**

If the the store type assign Dine-in
**the only selected is Dine-in**

[image: Output that I like]

Take a look i assign Dine-in,Take-out,Home Delivery,Drive Thru.

the result all checkbox must be selected.

Thanks..

Comment: You didn't share how checkbox is inserted/created ?

Comment: I will replace the statement thanks

Comment: Can you share any live demo ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by return the data as array and then write the following:

```
@php 
 $data =explode(',',$value->store_type);
@endphp

<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
<select multiple name="store_type[]" required="">
    <option selected="" disabled="">{{$value->store_type}}</option>
    <option value="Dine-in" {{in_array('Dine-in',$data)?'selected':''}}>Dine-in</option>
    <option value="Take-out" {{in_array('Take-out',$data)?'selected':''}}>Take-out</option>
    <option value="Home Delivery" {{in_array('Home Delivery',$data)?'selected':''}}>Home Delivery</option>
    <option value="Drive Thru" {{in_array('Drive Thru',$data)?'selected':''}}>Drive Thru</option>
</select>   
<label>Store Type</label>
</div>
```

Comment: $data ? where it came from?

Comment: I mean declared

Comment: from database the options you store

Comment: this is  the data . {{$value->store_type}}

Comment: tell me about results

Comment: I find other solution but so complicated. <?php 

                 $array = $value->store_type;
                 
                 $x = explode(',',$array);
                 echo "<select multiple>";     
         foreach($x as $value_selected)
         {  
          echo "<option selected>".$value_selected."</option>";
         }
         echo "</select>";

                ?>

Comment: can share the code you return from it the  $value->store_type

Comment: is $value->store_type return array

Comment: if its return array you can directly write the code i share and it will work fine

Comment: collection or what

Comment: when you do this  $data =explode(',',$array);

Comment: its converted to array now

Comment: and use $x as $data

Comment: i edit the code above try this code now and tell me the result

Comment: thanks ali. your code much be good. thanks ali i give you like (Y) thanks